# in R compute portfolio daily return from a trade matrix

Tags: r, loops, quantmod, performanceanalytics

Dear stackoverflowers,

TRADES is a 2000 rows trades P&L matrix, head.matrix(TRADES) gives:

> ### Date  P&L
>
> 20170101        90
>    20170101        100
>    20170102        -50
>    20170102        35
>    20170102        180

I need to compute the daily portfolio P&L and store it to a new matrix. The problem is that the number of trades for each day is not constant.

I can subset the trades regarding their dates and store all the same date trades into a new matrix with for instance for 1st of January 2017:
    `20170101 <- TRADES[grep("20140101", TRADES$Date), ]`

Then I can sum to get the daily P&L and store it to my daily returns matrix with: 
    `DailyReturns$20170101 <- sum(20170101$P&L)`

But I don't know how to make a loop to repeat this operation for all the trades, could someone please help me on this? Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `data.frame` or you can convert your matrix to a `data.frame`:

```
head(df)
#      Date  PL
#1 20170101  90
#2 20170101 100
#3 20170102 -50
#4 20170102  35
#5 20170102 130

aggregate(PL~Date, data=df,sum)
#      Date  PL
#1 20170101 190
#2 20170102 115
```

Comment: TY Marcelo that's what I needed!